# How to evalaute a CBIR model performance without ground truth?

Tags: python, evaluation, precision-recall, cbir

I implemented a content-based image retrieval(CBIR) model using Convolutional Autoencoders (neural networks). When given a query image to the model, I get five retrieval results from the database.

But to evaluate the CBIR model, there is no ground truth. Metrics like precision and recall need ground truth.

How can I evaluate the model without ground truth?